# League of Legends camera center arrow option

Tags: league-of-legends

How do I enable the option in League of Legends, which enables a large arrow upon my character when pressing space to center the camera? Is it even in the game?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like it's something from the tutorial

Comment: It could be, havent donw the turtorial in 5 years or so

Comment: Could you also show a screen shot so I know for sure?

Comment: No, i cant find it anymore, thats why I ask the question here. It would be easy to find it myself if I had a screen shot

Comment: I dont think Ive ever seen or heard of this arrow in my 5-ish years of playing

Comment: What does the arrow mean anyway? Why do you want it ? We might be able to help to find some sort of replacement at least.

Comment: well if a teamfight gets messy, it surely would help I think. And i saw it definetly somewhere, Well maybe it was a mod or something

Comment: This also happened in One-for-all, the screen shots may have been from that game mode?

Comment: Images added from [this forum post](http://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support-en/oMETE6cw-what-is-this-thing-around-my-champ?show=flat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the options menu with <kbd>esc</kbd> and go to the *Interface* tab. In the *Notifications* section, there will be a checkbox labelled *Champion Highlight on Camera Center*. Just check it and every time you center your camera, there will be an arrow indicator on top of your character.

[image: The interface tab of the options menu, with the Champion Highlight on Camera Center option highlighted.]

There is no official announcement of this feature, but it appears that it was released on [patch 6.24](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-624-notes).

Comment: Is it a new feature introduced in patch 7.1?

Comment: I forget the patch but it's a (relatively) new feature.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is not arrow that will be over a character's head. If you want to lock the camera on your character, you will have to enable the camera lock in settings or toggle it with Y (the default key to toggle camera locking). If you have a image you could provide, it would help.

Edit: The latest patch (7.1) and above should let you center your camera and have an arrow above the character's head.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such Feature in the game but I could think of two things that you describe.

- A visual indicator to a debuff (Nautilus R, Vi R, etc.) that got changed to an arrow by a (custom) skin.
- A 3rd party program that highlights your character if you center your camera.

Now while the first one is in a greyzone the second one is definitely forbidden to use, since Riot doesn't allow software that meddles with the game itself.

The only indicator that is in the game by default is a small circle around your character in some custom game modes like Hexakill or One for all.

Comment: Yeah. It might only have been an edited screenshot. But i remember it being blue in that LoL style.